# Floating point literal syntax

Tags: java

Following these two lines:

```
float f1 = 2E10f;
float f2 = 0x2P10f;
```

The output is:

```
2.0E10
2048.0
```

Respectively.

So my question is:

What is E10 and P10 equivalent to in decimals?

I think E10 equivalent to 10<sup>10</sup>, is that true?

Comment: E10 is scientific notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**E** and **P** are exponent indicators in [floating point literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).
You can also express number in decimal (base 10) or hexadecimal (base 16).

- `2E10f` is `2*10^10` (decimal base with exponent indicator)
- `0x2P10f` is `2*2^10` (hexadecimal base with binary exponent indicator)

Answer (score 0):

> I think E10 equivalent to 10^10(10 to the power of 10), is that true?

Yes. Proof:

Use [`BigDecimal#toPlainString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29):

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2.0E10).toPlainString());
```

Output will be 20000000000.

Meaning that E10 is 10<sup>10</sup>. ∎